# UVM Monitor behaves differently based on sequence of two statements

Tags: simulation, system-verilog, uvm

In UVM monitor when below two statements are added in `run_phase` as below, value sampled in `tr.pkt` is correct as per `data_in`. But if the order of statement is reversed, `tr.pkt` sampled is incorrect (`'h0` sampled). Anybody seen it before?

```
tr.pkt.push_back(this.wr_if.mon_clk_blk.data_in);
`uvm_info("",$sformatf("Write Monitor data = %0h", this.wr_if.mon_clk_blk.data_in), UVM_NONE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `data_in` is being updated in the same time step as the UVM montitor's execution.
In the scheduler, `push_back()` executes in the active region and `` `uvm_info() `` happens in the observed region. Another process would have updated `data_in` in the reactive region or latter scheduled active region. By reversing the `.push_bach()` / `` `uvm_info() `` order gives an opportunity the other thread to assign `data_in` before re-entering the active region to perform `.push_bach()`. Zero time glitches (such as `#0` in the design), could also relate to the unexpected values.

One way to guarantee both `.push_bach()` and `` `uvm_info() `` get the same value is to create a temporary variable that samples `data_in`. Example:

```
sampled_data = this.wr_if.mon_clk_blk.data_in;
tr.pkt.push_back(sampled_data);
`uvm_info("",$sformatf("Write Monitor data = %0h", sampled_data), UVM_NONE)
```

Comment: Thanks. All the assignment in design are w/o delay on posedge of clock . I will also try to add setup/hold in interface to see whether it helps.